# Is it possible to amend a failing build on Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci

I submitted [this pull request](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/pull/1017) and the Travis-CI build failed.

I pushed another commit to fix the failing test and the second build failed.

I posted  [this comment](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/pull/1017#issuecomment-255951758) asking why is it falling (I could not reproduce locally and I noticed this failure on other pull requests).

One day after I posted [this comment](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/pull/1017#issuecomment-255951758) I noticed that the build status is passing and the failing job which I linked to shows that the job finished successfully.

When I look in the [pull request build history](https://travis-ci.org/socketio/socket.io-client/pull_requests) I notice my first failing build and my second build which it now says it passed.

But I cannot find my second failing build.

Can anyone explain how something like this can happen?

Is there any way to find and see that failing build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you restart a build on Travis CI, the previous build log is lost at the moment.

It's possible that the build failure is intermittent hence restarting the build might make it fail again.

Comment: Thanks. I also think the failure is intermittent.  However I wish there was a way to see the log of the previous run.